# How To Deal With Spaces In a bat File?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I'm trying to make a simple bat file that launches two programs at once. The only problem is that one program has spaces in its name. I've tried every solution that I've found so far and can't come up with anything, it just stops looking at the first space. The other program did have spaces in it's name, but simply renaming it so that it didn't have spaces fixed the issue.Renaming the second program didn't work though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the code I have:

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Users\Jordan\Desktop\Work"
start BDOFPSBooster.exe

cd "D:\BDO"
start "Black Desert Online Launcher.exe"

exit
```

Comment: What is the filename exactly? Does the folder name contain space too? did you tried to put them in `"`s?

Comment: @Máté Juhász The folder name does not have spaces. The directory is simply D:\BDO. the filename is Black Desert Online Launcher. I have tried quotes, but they don't work.


Edit: I shouldn't say quotes don't work. Adding quotes simply opens a cmd window with the name of the program.

Comment: Replace `cd "D:\BDO"` with `cd /d "D:\BDO"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The START command in its minimal form takes two arguments: the title of the window and the program to launch. Also be sure to switch to the D: drive by simply typing 'D:' before using any relative path. Try using:

```
D:
cd "D:\BDO"
start "BDOL" ".\Black Desert Online Launcher.exe"
```

Comment: Using just `cd /d "D:\BDO"` is easier ...